# Instance variable isn't accessible from method

Tags: coffeescript

I'm new to CoffeeScript but I have written a class with a constructor which assigns attributes to this. In my function these attributes aren't defined. Does anybody have an idea?

```
class ProcessVisualisation
  constructer: (width, devMode = false) ->
    @objProcess = null
    @config =
      devMode: false

  loadProcess: (processPath) ->
    console.log("loadProcess") if (@config.devMode)  # <- config is not defined
    that = @;
    that.processPath = processPath
    $.getJSON @processPath, {}, (response) ->
      that.onProcessLoaded response

pv = new ProcessVisualisation(1023, true)

pv.loadProcess "data/process.json"
```

Comment: s/constructer/constructor/;

Comment: Typo: `constructor` ends in `or` rather than `er`.

Comment: To be fair, it is not easy for someone new to coffeescript or even javascript to debug a typo like this one, since it will not give you any error.

Comment: Besides the typo `constructor`, you might not need `that` too, just use  [CoffeeScript fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, fix `constructer` and the function arrow.

```
class ProcessVisualisation
  constructor: (width, devMode = false) ->
    @objProcess = null
    @config =
      devMode: false

  loadProcess: (processPath) =>
    console.log("loadProcess") if (@config.devMode)
    @processPath = processPath
    $.getJSON @processPath, {}, (response) =>
      @onProcessLoaded response

pv = new ProcessVisualisation(1023, true)

pv.loadProcess "data/process.json"
```